# Excel 2010: Home tab is blank

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office-2010, microsoft-excel-2010, ribbon

A user on our network has somehow managed to empty out their home tab in Excel. I've not had much luck finding a fix on Google. Does anyone have any ideas how to fix this?

[image: Screenshot]

The tab cannot be expanded in the "customize ribbon" options area and trying to reset doesn't do the trick either. It's like the user has removed all the sub-cats from the Home area manually.

I haven't performed an Office repair yet, but I'm willing to give that a go if it would fix the problem.

Comment: Are there any add-ins being loaded? Is there a Personal file being loaded in the background? (You can easily check by looking at the available projects in VB Editor [alt+f11]) Does this occur with every worksheet?

Answer (score 0):

This link should help - [Customize the Ribbon - Reset only the selected tab](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/customize-the-ribbon-HA010355697.aspx#_Toc266866033) (from the microsoft support). You should be able to reset the tab and restore it's content that way.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the replies guys. I ended up just performing a standard Office Repair, which did the trick. @LightningIsMyName, thanks for the link, but the "Reset only selected tab" option was grayed out in the Customize Ribbon window for whatever reason. This question can now be closed/answered.